# OSX Mac App Store: how to install a daemon shell script

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, mac-app-store

I'd like to write an app for the Mac App Store that involves installing a daemon. The daemon can be a dead-simple "Hello World" shell script, in either Bourne shell or Python. It should run automatically each time the machine boots.

I tried to get the script installed using `packagemaker`, but was never able to quite figure it out (and then later learned that packagemaker was not compatible with the App Store anyway).

Is there a way to install a shell script, such that it runs automatically on reboot for Mac App Store apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe Mac App Store applications are allowed to run background processes. That's cited [here](http://lifehacker.com/5726764/why-the-mac-app-store-sucks), as an example (I have not read the technical guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

Possible change/flexibility in policy:
http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/wlancontroller/id415633950?mt=12

Seems to be almost a background app, which sends data to a central server that has a web interface.

I would not have expected this to be accepted, but it has.