# Will Apple accept daemons in the Mac App Store?

Tags: cocoa, daemon, mac-app-store

I have a normal cocoa app with the UI that communicates with a daemon. Will apple allow this? Are there any examples of applications that have already been accepted that has a similar function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is answered here I believe [Mac App Store Background Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702160/osx-mac-app-store-how-to-install-a-daemon-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible change/flexibility in policy:

http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/wlancontroller/id415633950?mt=12

This app seems to be almost a background app, as it has a very minimal UI. It runs constantly and sends data to a central server that has a web interface.

I would not have expected this to be accepted, but it has.